# In C, I'm wondering how to base the way a string is handled based on the value of the first character in the string?

Tags: c, string, scanf

I have been assigned to write a program that takes in an octal, hex, or quaternary number and returns that number in the other two bases using bit-wise operators. Well, I have designed the necessary algorithm to perform the conversions but I am so new to C that I cannot figure out how to format the input. Each input needs to be preceded by an 'H', an 'O', or a 'Q' in order to specify which base is being input. So, I am wondering how to input a string so as to be able to store the remainder of that string based on the value of the first character in the string. For example, if the user entered `HFEEDFACE`, how could I read in the 'H' so as to be able to make the necessary conversions on the remainder of the string?

Comment: Strings in C are just null-terminated sequences of characters.  If you have a string `char *input = "HFEEDFACE";`, then `input[0]` is `'H'`, and `(input+1)` is the string `"FEEDFACE"`.

Comment: `if(string[0] == 'Q') value = strtol(&string[1], NULL, 4);`

Comment: @abelenky Ooops, was typing too fast;  fixed now.

Comment: Thanks Guys. The strtol function looks like it might be what I need. Thanks again. BTW, why the down votes? Too ambiguous or what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose your input string is `char* input`.

The first letter would be `input[0]`, and the remainder of the string would be at `input+1`.

Here is how you can implement the function which calls your algorithm with the correct arguments:

```
#define OK     0
#define ERROR -1

int Convert(const char* input,char* output)
{
    switch(input[0])
    {
    case 'H':
        return Algorithm(input+1,output,16);
    case 'O':
        return Algorithm(input+1,output,8);
    case 'Q':
        return Algorithm(input+1,output,4);
    }
    return ERROR;
}

int Algorithm(const char* input,char* output,int base)
{
    // Add your implementation here
    // Return OK or ERROR at the end
}
```

Comment: You're welcome :) ... thought you were supposed to implement `strtoul` yourself. You can still use the above suggestion and call `strtoul` from function `Algorithm`.